# Trigger function on click if View has a certain class (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a `div` generated by a backbone.js view. When the user clicks on this `div`, a class `active` is added to the `div` and the function `addToSet` is executed.

**Problem:** I want another function to be triggered when the View's `div` has the class `active`. However, my attempt shown below always cause `addToSet` function to run when its clicked.

Now, I remove `'click': 'addToSet'` from the `events` function, leaving only `'click .active': 'removeFromSet'`. Clicking on the `div` does not cause anything to happen! Is this because the event handler cannot select the `div` of the view itself, just the elements inside it?

Any idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks!

**JS Code**

```
SetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'modal_addit_set',

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal_addit_set').html() ),

    events: {
        'click': 'addToSet',
        'click .active': 'removeFromSet'
    },

    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.post_id = opts.post_id;
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        if(this.model.get('already_added'))
            $(this.el).addClass('active');
        return this;
    },

    addToSet: function() {
        $.post('api/add_to_set', {
            post_id: this.post_id,
            set_id: this.model.get('id'),
            user_id: $('#user_id').val()
        });
    },

    removeFromSet: function() {
        $.post('api/remove_from_set', {
            post_id: this.post_id,
            set_id: this.model.get('id')
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These events:

```
events: {
    'click': 'addToSet',
    'click .active': 'removeFromSet'
}
```

don't work and you sort of know why. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. The `callback` may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct function body. Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

So your `'click': 'addToSet'` binds `addToSet` to a click on the view's `el` itself but `'click .active': 'removeFromSet'` binds `removeFromSet` to a `.active` element *inside* the view's `el`.

I think the easiest solution is to have a single event:

```
events: {
    'click': 'toggleInSet'
}
```

and then:

```
toggleInSet: function() {
    if(this.$el.hasClass('active')) {
        $.post('api/remove_from_set', {
            post_id: this.post_id,
            set_id: this.model.get('id')
        });
    }
    else {
        $.post('api/add_to_set', {
            post_id: this.post_id,
            set_id: this.model.get('id'),
            user_id: $('#user_id').val()
        });
    }
}
```

You could use an instance variable instead of a CSS class to control the branching in `toggleInSet` if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to use a [:not(.active)](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector for one of your event delegates?  This may help differentiate between the two scenarios.

Something like this:

```
events: {
   'click :not(.active)' : callback1
   'click .active' : callback2
}
```

Comment: This is a much better/cleaner solution IMO :)